# Create an Angular 2 app inside no Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, deployment

I've created an Angular 2 app inside a normal javascript project and I need to use some files (.CSS, .JS, etc) outside the Angular app, but if I use the CLI with command `ng serve` it creates the app in the `http://localhost:4200/`, and the app works, but these files outside the angular app they won't be loaded. So I have to deploy the app with `ng build --prod` to get these files and see the real result. But I think this is not the best way as I have to deploy the app for every change in the code.

So, is there any way to manage this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify the question: the Angular app needs to use some assets that are located out of its `src` folder? Maybe a quick outline of your current directory structure would help.